# Is Redis HMSET deprecated?

Tags: node-redis

In https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis readme, `HMSET` command is mentioned. However, I see [`redis` documentation](https://redis.io/commands/hmset) is saying `hmset` is deprecated, is `HMSET` deprecated in latest `node-redis` version `3.2.1`? what `redis` engine version `node-redis` `3.2.1` is using?

Answer (score 0):

short answer: it's not (but this is not the answer you're looking for).

long answer:
`node-redis` package will use the redis engine of the redis server instance being connected to.

e.g. the client will not complain about `HMSET` deprecation when connected to redis server >=2.0,<4.0

here's the issue on `node-redis` repository tracking the implementation of `HSET` command https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis/issues/1564